# AngularJS - accessing Attributes of a DOM element outside Angular

Tags: angularjs

How do I get `DOM` element [`Attributes`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.%24compile.directive.Attributes) similar way (outside angular) I get `$scope` `(angular.element(element).scope())` ?

I need this so I can use `$animator` service on some element that is being inserted into `DOM`

the part of my code would look like:

```
var element = $compile(template,scope);
var attrs = ? // I would do element.attrs(), 
              // but this won't work as it does not perform normalization
var animation = $animator(scope,attrs);
animation.enter(element,parent);
```

Comment: for future reference, you are going to get more people looking at your question if you include the `javascript` tag.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me so you'll just need to know the attributes you're looking for...

```
console.log( angular.element(element)[0].getAttribute('class') );
```

actually this should then work too:

```
var attrs = angular.element(element)[0].attributes;
```